# why we need outer spin button to remove arrows from number

Tags: html, css, vendor-prefix

What is the different between inner-spin-button and outer-spin-button, when I use only inner-spin-button its work successfully in google chrome, so why do we need outer-spin-button

```
.removeNumberArrow::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.removeNumberArrow::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

and what does this syntax mean

```
.removeNumberArrow::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.removeNumberArrow::-webkit-outer-spin-button
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-outer-spin-button --- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-outer-spin-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inner-spin` and `outer-spin` are part of some legacy code. That's why they ask to use both pseudo-selectors when formatting spinners.

```
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

[Webkit official documentation](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls#inputelement)

```
.removeNumberArrow::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.removeNumberArrow::-webkit-outer-spin-button
```

The selectors here mean to select all elements which has class `removeNumberArrow` and with them choose pseudo elements `-webkit-inner-spin-button` and `-webkit-outer-spin-button` and format them with their appearance as `none`.